# Run UPDATE query on SELECT query result

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla3.0

I want to run an UPDATE query on a record after selecting it.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
   ->select(array('p.*', 'u.id', 'u.name' ,'pr.*'))
   ->from($db->quoteName('#__chichi_photos', 'p'))
   ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__users', 'u') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('p.userID') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('u.id') . ')')
   ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__chichi_profile', 'pr') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('pr.userID') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('u.id') . ')')
   ->where($db->quoteName('p.id') .'=' . $photoID .'');

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadRow();
```

I want to run an UPDATE query on a field in #__chichi_photos table that has an id in the result and if possible do it with a single query statement.

Basically what i want to do is update "hits" column on the field after it is selected. Thank You.